# Device destroyed by BeTools flashing tool

Tags: rom-flashing, system-error, fonts

To start from the beginning:

I have an old device with Android 5.1 that I rooted, and attempted to install a new font, called Lovecraftimus. I added a entry to the `fonts.xml` file that directed font calls for Lovecraftimus to use `/system/fonts/Lovecraftimus.otf`. I rebooted, and was instantly cycled through an endless amount of `Unfortunately, System UI has stopped` messages.he manufacturer sent me the full set of .img system images, with a ROM flashing tool called BeTools. When I flashed the images to my device (following the instructions), it said it was completed successfully. However, when I booted my tablet, the screen didn't work. I got a black screen with a few white/grey lines around the edges in bootloader, recovery mode, and factory testing menu. When I booted it (it booted perfectly, besides the screen error), turned the screen off, and back on again, I got a white screen with some colored lines. I can still use the touchscreen: I unlocked it (sound), pressed the Home button (vibration), changed the brightness (backlight), and turned on the flashlight (flash).

I would flash it using ADB but it does not appear in the ADB list. I get:

```
List of devices attached
```

I do, however, get a blank media device (its SD card).

How can I fix this? I would try BeTools again, but my temporary access code expired.

Comment: It sounds like you flashed a firmware for a different variant of you device that has an integrated graphics chip or visa versa ... If you have a MTK device you can just flash LK.bin and repair the graphics configuration

Comment: @Zillinium I do have an MTK device (if I plug it into Linux with a USB cable, it sometimes reads it as MediaTek K107 for a brief period), but how do I repair the graphics configuration? I can't find an answer without an unlocked bootloader or USB debugging enabled.